# ScreenCapturerAndroid without addSink

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I am trying to create screen share app using WebRTC.
Everything works as expected but I need to make call to addSing with a sink.
The only sink that worked was SurfaceViewRenderer.

```
    VideoTrack videoTrack = mPeerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);
    SurfaceViewRenderer localView = mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.localView);
    localView.setMirror(true);
    localView.init(mEglBaseContext, null);

    videoTrack.addSink(localView);
```

I want to make it work without displaying the local stream in the app.

Thanks

more code:
init:
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(this).createInitializationOptions());

```
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();

    DefaultVideoEncoderFactory defaultVideoEncoderFactory new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(mEglBaseContext, true, true);

    DefaultVideoDecoderFactory defaultVideoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(mEglBaseContext);

    mPeerConnectionFactory = PeerConnectionFactory.builder()
            .setOptions(options)
            .setVideoEncoderFactory(defaultVideoEncoderFactory)
            .setVideoDecoderFactory(defaultVideoDecoderFactory)
            .createPeerConnectionFactory();

    SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("sThread", mEglBaseContext);

    VideoCapturer videoCapturer = createScreenCapturer();//usign org.webrtc.ScreenCapturerAndroid
    VideoSource videoSource = mPeerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(videoCapturer.isScreencast());

    videoCapturer.initialize( surfaceTextureHelper, getApplicationContext(), videoSource.getCapturerObserver() );

    videoCapturer.startCapture(mScreenW, mScreenH, 30);

    VideoTrack videoTrack = mPeerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("100", videoSource);
    SurfaceViewRenderer localView = mChatHeadView.findViewById(R.id.localView);
    localView.setMirror(true);
    localView.init(mEglBaseContext, null);
```

//if I comment this out nothing works on the other side of the channel
        videoTrack.addSink(localView);

```
    mMediaStream = mPeerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("mediaStream");
    mMediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);

    mSignalingClient = new SignalingClient();
    mSignalingClient.init(this,mServURI);

//create the connection:
private PeerConnection getConnection() {
    PeerConnection peerConnection = mPeerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(mIceServers, new PeerConnectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
            super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
            try {
                mSignalingClient.sendIceCandidate(iceCandidate, socketId);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                showError("",e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            super.onAddStream(mediaStream);
        }
    });

    peerConnection.addStream(mMediaStream);

    return peerConnection;
}

public void onOfferReceived(JSONObject data){
    PeerConnection peerConnection = getConnection();

    ....
    //set remote description
    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(
            new SdpAdapter(),
            new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.OFFER, sdpData)
    );

    peerConnection.createAnswer(new SdpAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sdp) {
            super.onCreateSuccess(sdp);
            mPeerConnectionMap.get(socketId).setLocalDescription(new SdpAdapter(),sdp);
            .....
        }
    }, new MediaConstraints());
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by 'without displaying the local stream'? It will only display if you add a sink to it, right?

Comment: Hello,

I am sorry I was not clear on the problem.

The problem is that if I do not call addSink stream is not working on the remote.
I tried different tricks but the only way to get it working on the remote (html page) is using the SurfaceViewRenderer as a sink.

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't need to addSink on android side to get it to show up on remote. Could you show the code where you are sending your local track to remote?

Comment: Hello,

I just put more code in the original question.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, the remote screen would only render if I also rendered it locally. The way I fixed it was to move my variables to member variables in the class instead of variables defined inside the function. I am guessing this is due to some issues with garbage collection.

For example, from this:

```
class VideoTrackManager {

    private VideoTrack createTrack() {
        VideoCapturer capturer = new ScreenCapturerAndroid(mediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onStop() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
                }
        });

        PeerConnectionFactory pcFactory = webRTCModule.mFactory;

        EglBase.Context eglContext = EglUtils.getRootEglBaseContext();
        SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("ScreenCaptureThread", eglContext);
        VideoSource videoSource = pcFactory.createVideoSource(capturer.isScreencast());
        capturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, reactContext, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VideoTrack track = pcFactory.createVideoTrack(id, videoSource);
        track.setEnabled(true);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int fps = 30;
        capturer.startCapture(width, height, fps);

        webRTCModule.localTracks.put(id, new WebRTCModule.TrackPrivate(track, videoSource, null));

        return track;
    }

}
```

To this:

```
class VideoTrackManager {
    private PeerConnectionFactory pcFactory;
    private EglBase.Context eglContext;
    private SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private VideoCapturer capturer;

    private VideoTrack createTrack() {
        capturer = new ScreenCapturerAndroid(mediaProjectionPermissionResultData, new MediaProjection.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onStop() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "User revoked permission to capture the screen.");
                }
        });

        pcFactory = webRTCModule.mFactory;

        eglContext = EglUtils.getRootEglBaseContext();
        surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("ScreenCaptureThread", eglContext);
        videoSource = pcFactory.createVideoSource(capturer.isScreencast());
        capturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper, reactContext, videoSource.getCapturerObserver());

        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        VideoTrack track = pcFactory.createVideoTrack(id, videoSource);
        track.setEnabled(true);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int fps = 30;
        capturer.startCapture(width, height, fps);

        webRTCModule.localTracks.put(id, new WebRTCModule.TrackPrivate(track, videoSource, null));

        return track;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice! That makes sense that you would need the PeerConnection to be a member variable. In your example you returned the VideoTrack. However, in asker's example he returned the PeerConnection in the getConnection method. I wonder if it is considered still "in scope" after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I would try, rather than

```
mMediaStream = mPeerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("mediaStream");
    mMediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
```

Instead do:

```
            PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig =
                    new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(mIceServers);
    rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = PeerConnection.SdpSemantics.UNIFIED_PLAN;
    //Unified Plan is the new standard for SDP semantics and is needed to use transceivers

    RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit initOptions = new RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverInit(RtpTransceiver.RtpTransceiverDirection.SEND_ONLY);

peerConnection = mPeerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, 
                     new PeerConnection.Observer("tag"){

                           @Override
                           public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                           super.onIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                           try {
                               mSignalingClient.sendIceCandidate(iceCandidate, socketId);
                                }
                               catch (Exception e){
                               showError("",e);
                               } 
                           }
                     }

    peerConnection.addTransceiver(videoTrack);
```

I believe addTransceiver is the new way to do it, rather than onAddStream. On the browser side you will have to use onTrack. This [link](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/rtcrtptransceiver-explored/) has examples of using transceivers and onTrack in JS. I'm not certain if this will fix your problem, but at least you will be doing it the new way. Also, completely off-topic, I will mention that iOS webview doesn't seem to support WebRTC yet.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and let you know. Webview is on PC. This is really for custom android hardware.

Comment: @user4521550 did it work for you using the transceivers implementation? I am experiencing a similar issue and the remote stream is only working if I render locally just like you.

Comment: I found a solution, just posted an answer for what fixed it for me